# How can I find out if an AppleTV is currently connected to iCloud?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, icloud, apple-tv

On iOS and macOS, it's possible to check `ubiquityIdentityToken` to see whether the device is connected to iCloud.

But the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1935/_index.html) says: "On watchOS and tvOS, iCloud Drive is unavailable, ubiquityIdentityToken hence always returns nil for watchOS 2 WatchKit extensions and tvOS apps." ... "you might consider CloudKit when an iCloud service is needed on those platforms".

However, I might not want to use CloudKit, because it might require some additional permissions and additional setup. So is it possible to just find out if the Apple TV is currently connected to iCloud, so I could show the user an indication showing whether the device is offline or online? I'm using iCloud for saving the user progression in a game.